# access function arguments dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, dojo

I have a dojo define function like this one

```
define([
    // some param
]),function(foo, bar, baz, fooz, ...){
    return{
        // some custom code
    }
}
```

I would like to access dynamically to my function args(foo, bar, ...)

i know i could wrap it into var

```
foo : foo
```

and access it with

```
this[objectToCall].methodToRun();
```

in this example the calling should be

```
this.run('foo');

function run(objectToCall){ // foo    
    this[objectToCall].methodToRun(); // refer to foo
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this without wrapping it into a var ?

thx in advance

EDIT :

little step further
i could use `arguments` keyword.

```
function(foo, bar, baz, fooz, ...){
    var functionArguments = arguments;
    return{
        // some custom code
    }
}
```

but i can't access the foo object with `functionArguments['foo']`;

Comment: what part of `this['objectToCall'].methodToRun();` is `foo`?

Comment: Could you explain the `this['objectToCall'].methodToRun();` part ? I can't relate this with the first half of your question :(

Comment: sure, i have few object (foo, bar, ...) wich implements for example methodToRun(). I would like to dynamically select the right object, and run methodToRun() on it. If i select foo, this['objectToCall'].methodToRun should be this['foo'].methodToRun().
I already achieve this with wrapping object into var, but i would like to do it without the wrapping if possible

Comment: Can you use `functionArguments[0]`?

Comment: yes, it output this 
Object
foo: function (){
__proto__: Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution :

```
function(method){
    var len = functionArguments.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i ++){
        if(typeof functionArguments[i] === "object")
            if(functionArguments[i].name == method)
                functionArguments[i].test();
            }
```

and added a name param in my object's definition

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to use the "methodToRun" function kind of like an interface definition.

When you say would want to dynamically select the right object, it sounds like you are storing the object in some var somewhere in the code (ex: var selectedObject = foo;)

Being dynamic, you should be able to just call the method on the object using 
selectedObject.methodToRun();

(but it is now up to you to only supply objects that do in fact implement "methodToRun" otherwise you will get "object doesn't support this method" errors.)